# Scrapy: collect retry messages

Tags: python, scrapy

There is a maxim number of times for the crawler to retr, as documented [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-times). After reaching that, I got an error similar to the following:

`Gave up retrying <GET https:/foo/bar/123> (failed 3 times)`

I believe the message is produced by the code [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/retry.py#L77).

However, I want do some wrap up about the **give-ups**. Specifically, I wonder if it is possible to:

1. Extract the `123` part (an ID) of the URL and write these IDs to a separate file decently.
2. Access the `meta` info in the original `request`. [This documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments) might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subclass `scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry.RetryMiddleware` and override `_retry()` to do whatever you want with the request than is given up on.

```
from scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry import RetryMiddleware
from scrapy import log

class CustomRetryMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def _retry(self, request, reason, spider):
        retries = request.meta.get('retry_times', 0) + 1

        if retries <= self.max_retry_times:
            log.msg(format="Retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
                    level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider, request=request, retries=retries, reason=reason)
            retryreq = request.copy()
            retryreq.meta['retry_times'] = retries
            retryreq.dont_filter = True
            retryreq.priority = request.priority + self.priority_adjust
            return retryreq
        else:
            # do something with the request: inspect request.meta, look at request.url...
            log.msg(format="Gave up retrying %(request)s (failed %(retries)d times): %(reason)s",
                    level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider, request=request, retries=retries, reason=reason)
```

Then it's a matter of referencing this custom middleware component in your `settings.py`

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomRetryMiddleware': 500,
}
```